# Classify $\left(\Bbb{Z}_3^{\Bbb{Z}_3}, +\right)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let  $\Bbb{Z}_3^{\Bbb{Z}_3}$ be the set of all functions $\Bbb{Z}_3\to \Bbb{Z}_3$. Then how many elements are there in $\Bbb{Z}_3^{\Bbb{Z}_3}$ and what is $\left(\Bbb{Z}_3^{\Bbb{Z}_3}, +\right)$ isomorphic to?

I think the cardinality of $\left(\Bbb{Z}_3^{\Bbb{Z}_3}, +\right)$ is $27$ so it might be isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_3\times\Bbb{Z}_3\times\Bbb{Z}_3$.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\Bbb Z_3^{\Bbb Z_3}$ indeed has $|\Bbb Z_3|^{|\Bbb Z_3|} = 3^3 = 27$ elements. The group $(\Bbb Z_3^{\Bbb Z_3}, +)$ is abelian with $3f = 0$ for all $f \in \Bbb Z_3^{\Bbb Z_3}$. So it is isomorphic to the elementary abelian group $\Bbb Z_3 \times \Bbb Z_3 \times \Bbb Z_3$.